# MPI large data processing

Tags: c++, mpi, shared-memory, large-data-volumes

My application of MPI will read a series images to build a 3-D data. It is very large data( about 4 GB). I don't want the data distributed to every worker. I don't know how to do with this. Shared memory may be one solution. But how to use shared memory by using MPI. I have searched a lot about this, nothing good was found. Could someone give me suggestions or examples for large data processing by using MPI (BTW. I am using Open MPI implementation).
Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: MPI is an exclusively *distributed*-memory model of programming. For shared memory, you need something like OpenMP.

Comment: You *don't* want the data distributed to every worker? What are you actually asking how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are one-sided communications that were added to MPI-2. It is available in OpenMPI. For an introduction, you could have a look at http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1793/ .

The principle is that you create a window (an area of shared memory), then you can get or put data from that window. MPI should optimize it to use RMA when available. There are also mechanisms like fences to ensure synchronization across processes.